# scopeButtonTitles will not respond

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I have stumbled over sort of glitch. When I load this view first time, everything is okay:

[image]

If I go to the next view, my `UINavigationBar` looks like this:

[image]

If I press back now, I cant press the `scopeButton` which is displayed in the first image.

I know if I remove the `UISearchBar`(second image), I will be able to press the `scopeButtons` (first image).

This is my code for first image:

```
var searchBar = UISearchBar()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    secondContainerView.isHidden = true
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search"

    searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["0", "1"]
    searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    searchBar.barTintColor =  UIColor(red: 105/255, green: 185/255, 
    blue: 114/255, alpha: 1.00)
    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar




}
```

This is my code for the second image:

```
var searchBar = UISearchBar()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
```

}

I figured out that if I do this it works:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    searchBar.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Sadly this creates another problem, when I do the `swipeGesture` to go back, and stay on the current view, the `UISearchBar` is gone.

**Edit**:
If I tap the back button the `scopItems` won't respond, but on swipe, it works:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar

    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationItem.titleView = nil
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar


    }
```

Comment: Seems like a bug in Swift API. Better to add your own `SegmentedControl` instead of using `scopeBar`